# Chrome extension - Variable value not assigned deppending on interval duration

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables

The title sums up the weird problem I am having. I declare a global variable, execute a setInterval function which modifies that variable and deppending on the duration of the interval, the variable will look modified or not.

To be more clear, this simple background file code illustrates the situation:

```
var TabId=0;
var target= "https://google.com";

function start() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: target}, function(tab) {TabId=tab.id;});
    setInterval(Repeat, 30*1000); //repeat every 30 seconds
}

function Repeat(){
  chrome.tabs.remove(TabId);
  chrome.tabs.create({url: target}, function(tab) {TabId=tab.id;});
}


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(start);
```

I am surprised that for "short" intervals such as 10 seconds, the extension works just fine, but for 30 seconds, for example, it fails. It does nothing after the specified time is elapsed, and if you check in the console the value of TabId, it is still 0. It looks as if the code line

```
TabId=tab.id;
```

has never been executed, which is impossible because the tab has been created, right?

But there is something more: if you open the console for the background page before even firing the onClicked event, it seems to run ok as expected!

Can anybody help me understand what is going on here?
At first I thought it could have to do with the variable scope, but it doesn't make sense because for shorter intervals it works perfectly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

In my manifest file I had set "persistent" to *false*. This property enables you to work with an event page instead of a background page.

> Event pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.

So, after a while waiting for the interval to complete, the TabId is erased.
It was driving me crazy, but this morning I woke up with a hint for the solution.